# Use croppic to rotate images

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, html, css

I am using [croppic](http://www.croppic.net/) to crop images. Is there any possibility to extend its functionality to rotate the image, before sending it to crop. Something like this

```
var angle = 0;
$('#button').on('click', function() {
    angle += 90;
    $("#image").rotate(angle);
});
```

Here is the [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/s6zSn/)
I can manage to to rotate the image, but the cropped image is not in rotated position. Any idea?
Update:
Now the image is getting rotated. I have managed to keep rotated image by the same handler that uses crop method. But the cropped image in rotated position occurs only when the rotated image is in 180 rotation. When its in the 90/270, the image, obviously don't fit in the bounding box (if you have seen croppic) and I get a MemoryOutOfBound exception.

Here is the code:

```
public static Bitmap RotateImage(Bitmap bmpSrc, float theta)
{
    Matrix mRotate = new Matrix();
    mRotate.Translate(bmpSrc.Width / -2, bmpSrc.Height / -2, MatrixOrder.Append);
    mRotate.RotateAt(theta, new System.Drawing.Point(0, 0), MatrixOrder.Append);
    using (GraphicsPath gp = new GraphicsPath())
    {  // transform image points by rotation matrix
        gp.AddPolygon(new System.Drawing.Point[] { new System.Drawing.Point(0, 0), new System.Drawing.Point(bmpSrc.Width, 0), new System.Drawing.Point(0, bmpSrc.Height) });
        gp.Transform(mRotate);
        System.Drawing.PointF[] pts = gp.PathPoints;

        // create destination bitmap sized to contain rotated source image
        Rectangle bbox = boundingBox(bmpSrc, mRotate);
        Bitmap bmpDest = new Bitmap(bbox.Width, bbox.Height);

        using (Graphics gDest = Graphics.FromImage(bmpDest))
        {  // draw source into dest
            Matrix mDest = new Matrix();
            mDest.Translate(bmpDest.Width / 2, bmpDest.Height / 2, MatrixOrder.Append);
            gDest.Transform = mDest;
            gDest.DrawImage(bmpSrc, pts);
            return bmpDest;
        }
    }
}

private static Rectangle boundingBox(Image img, Matrix matrix)
{
    GraphicsUnit gu = new GraphicsUnit();
    Rectangle rImg = Rectangle.Round(img.GetBounds(ref gu));

    // Transform the four points of the image, to get the resized bounding box.
    System.Drawing.Point topLeft = new System.Drawing.Point(rImg.Left, rImg.Top);
    System.Drawing.Point topRight = new System.Drawing.Point(rImg.Right, rImg.Top);
    System.Drawing.Point bottomRight = new System.Drawing.Point(rImg.Right, rImg.Bottom);
    System.Drawing.Point bottomLeft = new System.Drawing.Point(rImg.Left, rImg.Bottom);
    System.Drawing.Point[] points = new System.Drawing.Point[] { topLeft, topRight, bottomRight, bottomLeft };
    GraphicsPath gp = new GraphicsPath(points,new byte[] { (byte)PathPointType.Start,
                      (byte)PathPointType.Line, (byte)PathPointType.Line, 
                      (byte)PathPointType.Line });
    gp.Transform(matrix);
    return Rectangle.Round(gp.GetBounds());
}
```

I think main issue is in the bounding box.

```
using (Bitmap rotate = new Bitmap(RotateImage(bmp, rotateAngle)))
{
    using (Bitmap cloneRotate = (Bitmap)rotate.Clone()) //getting error here
    {
        //some stuffs
        cloneRotate.save(mycroppedimageurl);
    }
}
```